# Calculate pandas DataFrame column by custom routine which accepts dictionary as input

Tags: python, pandas

There is pandas DataFrame with  numeric columns A1 and A2.

Task: create new column in DataFrame which is the result of the following  logical steps:

**Step #1.** Create the python dictionary  for every row in DataFrame. For example for the 1st row it may look like 
  {‘A1’:5, ‘A2’: 20}

**Step #2:** 
Apply for every python dictionary created on Step 1 the custom routine ***pack(dictionary)*** which accepts the python dictionary and returns the binary object.

If you are curious the routine ***pack*** is defined here
https://github.com/adamchainz/mariadb-dyncol/blob/master/mariadb_dyncol/base.py
but it should not matter.

**Step #3:** Store the binary object created by the ***pack*** routine in  new DataFrame column.

My attempt to solve it:

**Attempt #1.** 
Create array of python dictionaries - number of dictionaries=number of rows in DataFrame.  Apply ***pack*** to every dictionary. Create new column in DataFrame and populate it by result of pack method.

Problems: I do not know how to do it efficiently without looping over every row in DataFrame explicitly. A lot of intermediate objects are created.

**Attempt #2.**  I know how to create the new string column in DataFrame which looks like the python dictionary just with 1 line of code:

```
df['new']= '{"A1":'+str(df['A1'].item())+ 
           ',"A2":'+str(df['A2'].item()) +"}"
```

But I need to feed to ***pack*** routine the python dictionary, not a string.
I am thinking of work-around: introduce the routine which will read the string constructed above and will create the python dictionary from string and pass it to the ***pack*** routine. But it is very inefficient.

I want to avoid explicit looping over DataFrame rows, but cannot find the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2))

dicts = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    dicts.append({df.columns[0]: row._1, df.columns[1]: row._2})
```

You now have a list of dicts.

Step 2:

```
packed_blobs = [pack(x) for x in dicts]
```

Step 3:

```
dt = np.dtype(('column_name', 'blob_format'))
x = np.array(packed_blobs, dtype=dt)
df['new_col'] = x
```

I think this will work.  You'll have to make sure you know what the packed data looks like.

See [this structured array article](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) for details on the blob format.